# Cmake can't find Tesseract

Tags: tesseract, opencv3.0

im using cmake to compile opencv 3 with text module but it cant find Tesseract
(Tesseract: no)
im using tesseract 3.04 , vs2013 ,and windows.
i followed this article to install Tesseract
http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html
and this to compile opencv
http://audhootchavancv.blogspot.in/2015/08/how-to-install-opencv-30-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a precompiled binary compiled for vs2015 x64 with tesseract and extra modules https://github.com/cesardelgadof/OpenCVBinaries